# boost any cast trouble when reading a plist file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, any, boost-any

I'm reading some data from a plist file in visual c++.

data in file is somethig like this:

Caminando_001.png 
x
y
width 
height 
offsetX
offsetY
originalWidth
originalHeight

I read until x key value and then I do something like

int Left = boost::any_cast(iter->second); //iter is a pair std::string boost::any

That last line trows an exception (any bad cast) and I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: You're missing the template parameters on boost::any_cast, is that a typo? Also, if there was a `<float>` there, I think the value from the plist is a string, so any_cast will throw an exception, you should convert the string to int using some other method.

Comment: yes, it's int but when I post the question it doesn't show this part. What I do (when it trows an exception) is: int Left = boost::any_cast< int >(iter->second); //iter is a pair std::string boost::any

Comment: Can you any_cast it to string instead of int?